# Adding any external JS to vue.js creates unspecific ISE500 error

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iis, external-js

With one of my main projects, there is an unusual error/behavior that occurs when adding any external JS file to the index.html page of a vue.js application. With both applications, we use same frameworks (setups), but for whatever reason, this one generates a random error on our webserver (Windows Server 2019 because of Vue.JS over .net Core API) when we:

- Add google analytics to the index.html page OR
- Add twitter.js for embedded twitter/share support

When removing these lines, they go away.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="dark">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#1e2235">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#1e2235">
    <meta property="og:title" content="website.com">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="website.com">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://website.com/share.jpg">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://website.com/">
    <meta property="og:description" content="">
    <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="<%= BASE_URL %>apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="<%= BASE_URL %>site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#e0b055">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>website.com | dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="app-live"></div>
    <div class="kua-app" id="app"></div>

    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script> <!-- this is the triggering line -->
</body>
</html>
```

What reasons would adding any *.js files this way, including google analytics, result in a ISE500 and how could I fix it? My other project does not have this problem.

I will also include the webpack code, which is also the same as the other project I have.

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            "/api": {
                target: "http://localhost:5000",
                timeout: 6000,
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
                ws: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/api': '/'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    extractComments: true,

                    uglifyOptions: {
                        warnings: false,
                        parse: {},
                        compress: {},
                        mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
                        output: null,
                        toplevel: true,
                        nameCache: null,
                        ie8: false,
                        keep_fnames: false,
                    },
                })
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you post detailed error messages?

Comment: I would love to, but it literally doesn't provide any. It's a blank ISE500 error with no descriptions given.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this messages, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I learned that to get a descriptive answer of the ISE vs. the generic error is to load it on localhost. When I did, I got a more descriptive error which lead me to a gzip compression problem (error 500.52) (noted here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbc6c3d6-8fd8-4d45-ac74-a2e5394da502/getting-error-quotoutbound-rewrite-rules-cannot-be-applied-when-the-content-of-the-http-response) that occurred all of a sudden. 

I removed the static compression and the site works just fine. 

I would add this as an answer but this site does not let me, which is poor form imo.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. You can post your answer in the below answer and then mark it.